# EF5 many-many relationship entities

Tags: .net, .net-4.5, entity-framework-5

We are using the pre release version of EF5 and doing code first. I have an **Orders** model and a **Products** model (many<>many relationship). I created **OrderItems** model with OrderID, ProductId and Quantity fields. It is not auto-generating the link table. Below is the code :

```
Imports System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations

Public Class OrderItems
    Public Property OrderID As Long
    Public Property ProductID As Long
    Public Property Quantity As Integer
End Class
```

Do I have to annotate them as being required or link them explicitly by using the Association tag?

Answer (score 0):

I think in this case would be good idea to use **Code First Relationships Fluent API** http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/hh134698.aspx